# Why is `return` necessary in `match` arm when using `Result` in `main`?

Tags: rust, program-entry-point, rust-result

I am reading Rust by Example book. In this [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result.html#using-result-in-main) removing `return` in `Err(e) => return Err(e)` causes an error: ``` expected `i32`, found enum `Result`` ``` . Why is that?

What is the difference between `Err(e) => return Err(e)` and `Err(e) => Err(e)`?

Here is the code from the example:

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let number_str = "10";
    let number = match number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(number)  => number,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };
    println!("{}", number);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Note that the result of the `match` is being bound to `number`.  What could the type of `number` be?  In your version, the result of the match could be either of type `i32` or `Result`, and the type of `number` can only be one or the other, chosen at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    let number = match number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(number)  => number,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };
```

This says if `number_str.parse::<i32>()` returns an `Ok` to set `number` to `number`, an i32. If it returns an `Err` to immediately return `Err(e)`, which is a `Result`, from `main`, `number` is not set.

That's fine because `number` can only be an `i32` and `main` does return a `Result`.

```
    let number = match number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(number)  => number,
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    };
```

This says if `number_str.parse::<i32>()` returns an `Ok` to set `number` to `number`, an i32, same as before. If it returns an `Err` to set `number` to `Err(e)`, which is a `Result`.

`number` cannot be both an `i32` and a `Result`, so you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

All arms of a `match` have to have "compatible" types. This either mean they all  have the same type:

```rust
fn is_some<T>(opt: &Option<T>) -> bool {
  match opt {
    // both arms have type bool
    Some(_) => true,
    None => false,
  }
}
```

or some of the branches need to direct control flow away from the match in some way.

The main rule to keep in your head is that every variable in Rust needs a **single** type (ignoring variance w.r.t. lifetimes). In your case, if you didn't have the `return` keyword, what would be the type of `number`?

If the parse succeeds, `number` would be an `i32`. If it fails, it would be an `Err(ParseIntError)`. This isn't allowed, so you get a compile error.

However, if you `return Err(e)`, `number` will always be an `i32` (since `return` prevents the rest of the function running, so `number` doesn't need a type).

A similar thing applies to other control-flow keywords (e.g. `continue`, `break`, ...), as well as things that are guaranteed to not return, like `panic!()` (look up the `Never`/`!` type for more info)